# Resource tree not showing Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, user-roles

I am using Magento version 2.3.3

Resource Tree not showing while assigning custom resource to user.

[image: Resource Tree not showing]

Its giving some JSON syntax error in console as well

anyone here here, thanks in advance

Comment: I've the same problem. Have you find a solution?

Comment: The issue existed in Uber theme base module i have updated the xml file then it was fixed.

Comment: can you show me how did you fix the error ,
i am facing same issue what to fix in acl.xml file